# Restlet with Jetty Configuration

Tags: web-services, jetty, restlet

Dependencies:

```
RestLet 2.3
Jetty 9.4
```

MyServer.Java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.restlet.Component;
import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Component component = new Component();
        Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 5000);
        server.getContext().getParameters().add("useForwardedForHeader", "true");
        component.getDefaultHost().attach(new MyApplication());

        try {
            System.out.println("Going to start MyServer");
            component.start();
            System.out.println("Server started on port " + port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e, e);
        }
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
import com.myApp.resources.*;
import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/App", MyResource.class);
        return router;
    }
}
```

MyResource.Java

```
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Date;

@Path("/getDetails")
public class MyResource extends ServerResource{

    @GET
    @Path("/{number}")
    public Object getData(@PathParam("number") String number) {
        try {
            System.out.println("number: " + number);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok("Received", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Now I'm starting my application it starting with the following console log...

```
Going to start MyServer
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @291ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Ignoring deprecated socket close linger time
Starting the Jetty [HTTP/1.1] server on port 5000
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.14.v20181114; built: 2018-11-14T21:20:31.478Z; git: c4550056e785fb5665914545889f21dc136ad9e6; jvm 1.8.0_181-b13
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@3327bd23{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5001}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @446ms
Starting com.myApp.server.MyApplication application
Server started on port 5000
```

Now when I'm trying to get the result by using `localhost:5000/App/getDetails/5426`. I'm unable to get the response.
Even I'm getting following message on the console...

```
[qtp586617651-20] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /App/getDetails/GJ0125 java.io.IOException: Restlet exception
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also if any other way to implement then let me know.

Comment: You are using JAX-RS annotations in your resource. You have to use `org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.JaxRsApplication`

Comment: You mean @Path I define in MyResource?

Comment: All the annotations defined under `javax.ws.rs.*` are JAX-RS compliant annotations, and all annotations under `org.restlet.resource.*` are Restlet ones. Theres a story behind it. Restlet implemented REST much before Sun/Oracle/JCP/others came up with ReST based standards in Java, and called it JAX-RS. Hence when JAX-RS came out, a new JAX-RS extension was added in Restlet. `org.restlet.resource.*` needs `Application`. So `javax.ws.rs.*` needs `org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.JaxrsApplication`. Note the `ext` in full class name. The name JAX-RS was a take on the name JAX-WS(based on SOAP)